# Passing a parameter to SSRS via a URL

Tags: reporting-services, report, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass a parameter to an SSRS report via a URL. This is so I can extend the functionality of one of my other reports.

I've read many things on SO and forums but nothing has worked so far.

This is my URL http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSSRS_New2%2fStatusHistory&enrolmentNumber=11111

When the URL is entered, the report page will show, however the parameter will not be populated.

I've tried:

- setting the parameter to hidden, but it simply gives an error that there was no parameter entered
- changing Report.aspx? to ReportViewer.aspx? but this only renders a 404 error.
- changing from this

  - http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSSRS_New2%2fStatusHistory&enrolmentNumber=11111 to
  - http://servername/ReportServer?/SSRS_New2/StatusHistory&enrolmentNumber=11111
    which only results in sending me back to the root folder of my reports server

I'm purposefully only testing the URL at this stage and will implement into another report if I can get it working.

I'm now very confused as to what I can do. Can anyone please give any guidance on the correct way to write the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same code. u should map parameters with "&" operator.
and use report server full url.

="javascript:void(window.open('https://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMR_Enrollment_Everyone%2fGPS_Application_Notes&rs:Command=Render&VendorID=" & VendorID.Value & "','_blank','height=500,width=500,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes ,modal=yes'))"

Comment: Maybe I tagged the wrong thing as 'parameter-passing'. I'm simply looking to paste it as a URL into my browser to first understand the syntax. I wont be using any JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://<servername>/reportservername?/<pathname>/<reportname>&rs:Command=Render&<parameter>=<value>
```